# Структура проекта Java в Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, project

Привет, граждане!)
А кто может объяснить следующее поведение Eclipse?
Создаю такую вот структуру проекта (Maven если что)

```
|--/src
|----/java
|------/main
|--------Main.java
```

Когда запускаю, эклипс ругается, что файл java.main.Main.java не найден.

Но если я создаю структуру проекта таковой:

```
|--/src
|----/main
|------/java
|--------/main
|----------Main.java
```

То все работает корректно)) 
Из-за чего происходит такое поведение?

Заметил еще, если создать такую структуру:

```
|--/src
|----/main
|-------Main.java
```

То тоже ругается))

Comment: А как вы думаете? Может быть это потому, что пакет с корнем `java` уже существует и там находятся всякие другие библы `java.util`, `java.lang`, `java.io`, `java.awt` и прочее? Полный список https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Comment: я думаю, потому что в Maven [так положено](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: Тогда почему при добавлении папки main и создании в нем файла java не работает проект?

Comment: А каким образом вы создаёте первоначальную структуру проекта? Не пробовали просто создать новый проект по шаблону maven? File->New->Project...->Maven->Maven Project

Comment: Ещё попробуйте создать новый проект командой `mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app` затем перейдите в каталог, где у вас создался файл pom.xml и выполните команду `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Comment: Шаблон я создавал, да, все хорошо, работал с ним) 
Но у меня была проблема в непонимании правильной организации структуры проекта. А именно, как правильно создать package чтоб в нем запустился файл, как импортировать в один файл, другой файл с другого пакета и т.д. 
Поэтому я создавал с нуля все и разбирался в этом. И возник предыдущий вопрос)
А то, что проект Maven то неважно, мне кажется даже)
Главной идеей моей было разобраться как организовать структуру проекта) 
Но спасибо всем. Нашел кучу инфы в гугле и разобрался со всем этим )

Answer (score 1):

У maven своя структура проектов, отличная от структуры, которую Eclipse, да и любая другая IDE, использует по-умолчанию. Обычно корневой папкой для исходников считается `src` внутри папаки проекта, у maven-же это `src/main/java/`. Имена пакетов начинаются от корневой папки, т.е. в обычном случае после `src`, а у maven'а после `src/main/java/`